# Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Mail" not found

Tags: laravel

How can I resolve this error? I am trying to customize the default email template on laravel. This is the code for the controller that sends the email.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illumunate\Auth;

class EmailVerificationNotificationController extends Controller
{

public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }

    Mail::send('email.template', $request->user(), function($mail) use($data){
        $mail->to($request->user()->email, 'no-reply')->subject("Verify Email Address");
        $mail->from('admin@raketlist.com','testing');
    });

    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('status', 'verification-link-sent');
}
```

}

Comment: "use Mail;"   Add this into the controller  it will solve

Comment: After adding "use Mail;", I encounter this error [Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::send(): Argument #2 ($data) must be of type array]

Comment: pass the email id of "to" into the array  e.g: array($request->user()->email)

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;` to other uses.